# Need to call javascript file on <f:ajax> response in jsf

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

Actually I tried to call javascript file when my  response coming.In my code, I have toggle button and two divs are hide and show respective to toggle button value change.but when second div shows, want to call javascript file on every ajax call.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <h:outputLabel  class="col-lg-4 control-label" value="Apply on Company"></h:outputLabel>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
     <div class="left marginR10">
       <div class="normal-toggle-button toggle-custom-size">
           <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="nostyle" value="#{promocdbean.aplyOnCmpny}">
              <f:ajax execute="@this" event="change" render="prefbyselection" />
           </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>   
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </div>  <!-- End .form-group  -->
   <h:panelGroup id="prefbyselection" layout="block" >
     <h:panelGroup id="cmpnynm" layout="block" class="form-group" rendered="#{promocdbean.aplyOnCmpny }">
    <h:outputLabel for="cmpnyname" class="col-lg-4 control-label" value="Company Name" ></h:outputLabel>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <h:outputLabel  class="control-label"  value="Nirula'a Corner House Private Limited" ></h:outputLabel>
    </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup id="locatn" layout="block" class="form-group" rendered="#{!promocdbean.aplyOnCmpny}" >
       <h:outputLabel for="location" class="col-lg-4 control-label" value="Location" onfocus="loadScript()"></h:outputLabel>
         <div class="col-lg-5" >
            <h:selectOneMenu id="location"  value="#{promocdbean.location}" class="form-control" >
                 <f:selectItem itemValue="77" itemLabel="Nirulas (Preet Vihar)"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="76" itemLabel="Nirulas (19 Community center)"></f:selectItem>
         </h:selectOneMenu>
       </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: You seem to be new to JavaScript as well. The phrase "call javascript file" doesn't make any sense. Do you mean "load javascript file" (include a `/some.js` file) or "call javascript function" (invoke/execute `someFunction()`)? If you mean "load javascript file", then that would make even less sense because you don't need to load it everytime while staying on the same DOM. So can we assume that you actually meant to say "call javascript function"?

Comment: but I want to reload my Javascript file which sets dynamic componets and css for my JSF page.

Comment: This sounds really strange. Is it perhaps one whole bunch of inline script (which is executed immediately) instead of function(s) (which is only executed when you explicitly call it)? Why not wrapping it in a reusable function so that you can just invoke it when needed, without to download the whole inline script again and again?

Comment: Thanks for reply.I will try it.but still there is no way to reload js file on ajax response in jsf.

Comment: Sure there is. I'm only not seeing how it makes ever sense. I usually never answer questions asking for clumsy/weird/unthoughtful/wrong approaches. You'd better take a step back and elaborate about the concrete functional requirement for which you likely incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution. Otherwise every starter would think that I'd support/advocate it while I actually don't.